# Is there a way to use the JIRA rest api to search for issues that does not involve registering a connect app or being a site admin?

Tags: jira-rest-api

The documentation here does not mention something as simple as generating a test token that can be used in postman:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-search/#api-rest-api-3-search-get

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to be a site admin to use the REST API nor do you need to register any app, you can make a connection using any valid username as long as you have a valid, corresponding key + token.

Read [this article](https://confluence.atlassian.com/cloud/api-tokens-938839638.html) on how a user generates a key and token for their account.

Comment: The token worked for one hit to the api endpoint and then it gives me 401. Is that something that you encountered ?

Comment: No, it's not something I've encountered. By default, the tokens + keys for Jira cloud are valid forever, unless you deliberately set them to have a shorter life, for security reasons. I use my key + token almost every day of the week and I generated it years ago.